# concatenate several file remove header lines

Tags: python, unix, awk

What'd be a good way to concatenate several files, but removing the header lines (number of header lines not known in advance), and keeping the first file header line as the header in the new concatenated file?

I'd like to do this in python, but awk or other languages would also work as long as I can use subprocess to call the unix command.

Note:  The header lines all start with #.

Comment: Please post some examples (e.g. file 1 and file 2 with respective headers).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The file header lines start with `#`.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed. Sorry about the noise.

Comment: Do you know that mode ``'a'`` allows to write at the end of a file ? I ask you this because if you don't want to keep the first file untouched, you could write all the other files one after the other in the first one.

Comment: Are one of the files potentially very big ? Treatments of files depends on the fact if  files can easyly be completely read in RAM in one chunk or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using Python:

```
files = ["file1","file2","file3"]

with open("output_file","w") as outfile:
    with open(files[0]) as f1:
        for line in f1:        #keep the header from file1
            outfile.write(line)

    for x in files[1:]:
        with open(x) as f1:
            for line in f1:
                if not line.startswith("#"):
                    outfile.write(line)
```

You can also use the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module here:

> This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a
>   loop over standard input or a list of files.

```
import fileinput
header_over = False
with open("out_file","w") as outfile:
    for line in fileinput.input():
        if line.startswith("#") and not header_over:
            outfile.write(line)
        elif not line.startswith("#"):
            outfile.write(line)
            header_over = True
```

usage :`$ python so.py file1 file2 file3`

**input:**

file1:

```
#header file1
foo
bar
```

file2:

```
#header file2
spam
eggs
```

file3:

```
#header file3
python
file
```

**output:**

```
#header file1
foo
bar

spam
eggs

python
file
```

Comment: Thanks! would this be fast?  In my experience sometime python takes a long time to read long files.  Do you think there are faster options or this should be ok?

Comment: Are there other lines in the file that could start with '#', other than the header lines?

Comment: @Dnaiel I've added another solution using `fileinput` module.

Answer (score 7):

I would do as following;

```
(cat file1; sed '/^#/d' file2 file3 file4) > newFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def combine(*files):
    with open("result.txt","w+") as result:
        for i in files:
            with open(i,"r+") as f:
                for line in f:
                    if not line.strip().startswith("#"):
                        result.write(line.rstrip())



combine("file1.txt","file2.txt")
```

`file1.txt`:

```
#header2
body2
```

`file2.txt`:

```
#header2
body2
```

`result.txt`

```
body2body
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '
    ARGIND == 1 { print; next } 
    /^[[:space:]]*#/ { next }
    { print }
' *.txt
```

Comment: Your regex needs to be `/^[[:space:]]*#/` -- those named character have to go inside brackets.

Comment: @Birei `ARGIND` is `gawk` only.

Answer (score 1):

You could call a shell pipeline passing `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`

```
cat f.1 ;  grep -v -h '^#' f.2 f.3 f.4 f.5
```

Quick example

```
import sys, subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('''cat f.1 ;  grep -v -h '^#' f.2 f.3 f.4 f.5''', shell=True,
stdout=sys.stdout)
p.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys 

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    for line in open(sys.argv[i], "r"):
        if i == 1 or not line.startswith("#"):
            print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Run the script with the files as arguments and redirect the output to the result file:

```
$ ./combine.py foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt > result.txt
```

The header(s) will be taken from the first file of the argument list (`foo.txt` in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` version:

```
awk '!flag && /#/ { print; flag=1; next } flag && /#/ { next } 1' f1 f2 f3
```